# Issue removing a class from one DIV tag and adding to the next

Tags: jquery

I have 2 container divs with a class of `trislider`, and each of those has divs inside of it which are supposed to animate to a certain position.

the html is:

```
<div class="trislider">
     <div class="tri1"></div>
     <div class="tri1stroke stroke"></div>
     <div class="tri2"></div>
     <div class="tri2stroke stroke"></div>
     <div class="tri3"></div>
     <div class="tri3stroke stroke"></div>
     <div class="tri4"></div>
     <div class="tri4stroke stroke"></div>
</div> <!-- /.trislider -->

<div class="trislider">
    <div class="tri1"></div>
    <div class="tri1stroke stroke"></div>
    <div class="tri2"></div>
    <div class="tri2stroke stroke"></div>
    <div class="tri3"></div>
    <div class="tri3stroke stroke"></div>
    <div class="tri4"></div>
    <div class="tri4stroke stroke"></div>
</div> <!-- /.trislider -->
```

The problem is that at the end of the last animation, I want to remove the `active` class from the div whose children were animated, and add that `active` class to the next parent div and animate its children. The problem is that the second parent div never gets the `active` class.

```
$('div.trislider:first').addClass('active');
$('div.trislider:first').addClass('first');
$('div.trislider:last').addClass('last');

setInterval(function() {

            // $('div.trislider.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');

            $('div.trislider.active div.tri1, div.trislider.active div.tri1stroke').animate({
                'top': 0
            }, 1000);

            setTimeout(function() {
                 $('div.trislider.active div.tri2, div.trislider.active div.tri2stroke').animate({
                'top': 0
                }, 1000);
            }, 400);

            setTimeout(function() {
                 $('div.trislider.active div.tri3, div.trislider.active div.tri3stroke').animate({
                'top': 0
                }, 1000);
            }, 800);

            setTimeout(function() {
                 $('div.trislider.active div.tri4, div.trislider.active div.tri4stroke').animate({
                'top': 0
                }, 1000, function() {
                     $('div.trislider.active div.stroke').fadeOut('fast');
                     $('div.trislider.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
                });
            }, 1200);

        }, 5000);
```

But if I change the following line:

```
$('div.trislider.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
```

to:

```
$('div.trislider.active').next().addClass('active');
```

then the second `.trislider` gets the active class, but if I remove it first then it does not get it.

js fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7e1f3u95/1/

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for the issue?

Comment: @Snehal https://jsfiddle.net/7e1f3u95/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your last statement is in wrong place:
    $('div.trislider.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');

Place it here:
    $('div.trislider.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    }, 5000);

Just at the end of setInterval
complet function:
    setInterval(function() {

```
            // $('div.trislider.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');

            $('div.trislider.active div.tri1, div.trislider.active div.tri1stroke').animate({
                'top': 0
            }, 1000);

            setTimeout(function() {
                 $('div.trislider.active div.tri2, div.trislider.active div.tri2stroke').animate({
                'top': 0
                }, 1000);
            }, 400);

            setTimeout(function() {
                 $('div.trislider.active div.tri3, div.trislider.active div.tri3stroke').animate({
                'top': 0
                }, 1000);
            }, 800);

            setTimeout(function() {
                 $('div.trislider.active div.tri4, div.trislider.active div.tri4stroke').animate({
                'top': 0
                }, 1000, function() {
                     $('div.trislider.active div.stroke').fadeOut('fast');


                });
            }, 1200); 
    //should go here
    $('div.trislider.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: You mean after the last settimeout? I tried that, but it's the same. If you think I am doing it wrong then please try to do it in the fiddle.

Comment: and in any case I need all the timeouts to finish before it fires.

Comment: Ok I am adding the full setInterval function.Its working fine.Just checked in the firebug.

Comment: But that fires straight away, it does not wait for the timeout functions to finish right?

Comment: It does wait for timeouts to finish.Just tested it and checked the divs in firebug.Works fine.